# Providing disjoint functionality for a class

Tags: c#

I'm currently writing a charting application. I am using Zedgraph to display 2D plots. Within my application I need to display approx 8 different types of charts, and each one needs to provide slightly different functionality.

The issue here, is sometimes I have some "base " functionality that most classes will use, sometimes I have "added" functionality that some classes will use and other times its a mix-mash of these. On top of this, the data displayed in the charts is again disjoint, and the visual appearance is also disjoint.

Consider the following functionality that may apply to one or more charts:

- Ability for the chart to automatically scroll (with live data)
- Ability for the chart to zoom in the horizontal direction
- Ability for the chart to zoom in the vertical direction
- Ability for the user to edit points in the chart
- Ability for the user to select a region of data
- Ability for the user to change the scales of the chart
- Ability for the chart to "zoom to fit"
- Ability to ahve one,two,three or four vertical axes
- Ability to show a chart overlay
- etc

Bringing this all together, some functionality applies to all charts, some applies to a subset of charts, and some applies to individual charts. Currently I can see no hierarchy of functionality to implement.

My current implementation uses a base class (to provide global functionality that I can clearly see) and then I have two 'forks' off this base class, but I'm now stuck at how to implement the **disjoint** functionality over individual classes. I can't use an abstract class, as sometimes I need to inherit from multiple classes, but I don't want to provide an interface, as the code is exactly the same.

So, what do I do here? Do I maybe use extension methods to enable specific functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have so many aspects of functionality, that they they seem rather independent (any particular chart could have any sub-set of the features, or close to it), and that it would seem to me that these are the types of things that may change over time with the application, you would want to spend some up front time generalizing this rather than implementing them on a per-chart basis.

I would simply make a general purpose "Chart" user control and implement *all* of the features.  Then, for each feature, give it a boolean property to enable/disable it.  (i.e. `IsHorizontalScrollable`, `IsVerticalScrollable`, `IsSelectionEnabled`, `ArePointsEditable`)  Then each actual instance of the form just needs to set the appropriate properties of your more general form along with the actual data for it.

Comment: +1 Thanks, not a bad suggestion. Yea extension methods are probably not the right use here... as some things are mutually exclusive, I could just handle this in the property setters too.

Comment: @Simon Yeah, the general point is that you should start out with a single class that does *everything* and then have other classes using it that only expose a limited subset of what it's capable of.  Sometimes it's not desirable and it's better to start out with the shared subset and add to it, but here, due to the fact that there are so many permutations of options, and many different instances will be adding different overlaps of functionality, that would just be too hard.